# How to determine why a C program outputs unexpected messages?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, console

I'm trying to program in C on Eclipse, I have installed and configured MinGW, but I have a problem that I don't understand:

I have some simple code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    int num1,num2;

    setbuf(stdout,NULL);

    printf("enter two numbers");
    scanf("%d%d",&num1,&num2);

    if(num1>num2){
        printf("num1 is greater than num2");

    }else{
        printf("num2 is greater than num1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

After I compile and run, it shows me "Enter two numbers" and I enter two numbers, I can't see any further  output and keyboard function doesn't work on console screen, it doesn't give me an error, but it does show some strange output on console:

```
<terminated>

<terminated>(exit value: -1.073.741.515) CPS:exe
```

Comment: If you had compiled with warnings enabled (e.g. `-Wall`) [as you should always do], the original `scanf` would have been flagged by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

You're not reading in the values correctly:

```
scanf("%d%d",num1,num2);
```

The `%d` format specifier for `scanf` expect a `int *`, i.e. a pointer to an `int`, as an argument.  It needs the address of a variable to be able to write a value to where that address is stored.

You're instead passing the current values of `num1` and `num2` which are essentially garbage values because the variables have not been written to.

You instead want:

```
scanf("%d%d",&num1,&num2);
```

Comment: That is what I just make a mistake when I type the question. It is not the real problem. Something I don't know

Answer (score 0):

I don't kwon if the code you post is exactly the same as what you compiled, when I copy and compile the code you posted, gcc report an error at line:

```
printf("num2 is greater than num1);
```

There lost the ending quotation mark in printf();
After I fixed this error, it works well. My environment is

> Linux DESKTOP-7VH0PN1 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Oct 28 23:40:43 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

With gcc:

> gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
> Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.